# Cannot route access. "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, routes

I have problem to access in the route. I call the rute from the view and this route call the controller and send the argument to the view.

### web.php

```
Route::get('/ifa-policy-staff/{policy-id}', 'PolicyController@showPolicy')->name('policy');
```

---

### In the view (from I call)

```
<a href="{{ route('policy', $policy->id) }}">
```

### in controller (from I call the missing view)

```
public function showPolicy($policy){
   return view('ifa-policy-staff')->with("policy", $policy);  
}
```

What is wrong? I think is because Auth issue. I use Laravel Auth.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According To Laravel [Docs Route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#required-parameters)

You Can't Use **-** In Route Parameters

> Route parameters are always encased within {} braces and should consist of alphabetic characters, and may not contain a - character. Instead of using the - character, use an underscore (_). Route parameters are injected into route callbacks / controllers based on their order - the names of the callback / controller arguments do not matter.

In Closing, You Just Need To Change

`Route::get('/ifa-policy-staff/{policy-id}', 'PolicyController@showPolicy')->name('policy');`

TO

`Route::get('/ifa-policy-staff/{policy_id}', 'PolicyController@showPolicy')->name('policy');`

Best Regards,

hamza

Comment: o_o. Thanks a lot my friend

Comment: You Arr Welcome Could you Mark This Answer!